# reloading a page every time a minute rolls over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to these forms so apologies if my question is confusing, or unclear. I am wanting to know how to reload a webpage every time a minute rolls over using javascript. (Note I do not mean reloading it every 60 seconds) I have this bit of code running which keeps a clock going on the website:

```
function startTime() {
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
h = checkTime(h);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
h + "|" + m;
var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500); }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use the variable I already have, "s" to check if the page needs to be reloaded, perhaps with the if then statements in javascript, |If (s = 60) {location.reload();}| but I am not sure on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `s` will not reach `60`, better reload on `s === 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check every second is enough. getSeconds() returns [0, 59] so it's correct to check at 0 as @slash197 said. How about something like below:

```
const norefresh = () => {
  console.log('Not ready');
}

const refresh = () => {
  console.log('Time to REFRESH');
}

const check = () => {
  let t = new Date();
  if (t.getSeconds() === 0) {
    return refresh();
  }
  return norefresh();
}

setInterval(check, 1000);
```